# Is there a limit to the number of created events?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, events, threadpool

I'm developing a `C++14` `Windows` DLL on `VS2015` that runs on all `Windows` version >= `XP`.

#### TL;DR

Is there a limit to the number of events, created with [CreateEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682396(v=vs.85).aspx), with different names of course?

#### Background

I'm writing a thread pool class.
The class interface is simple:

```
void AddTask(std::function<void()> task);
```

Task is added to a queue of tasks and waiting workers (`vector <thread>`) activate the task when available.

#### Requirement

Wait (block) for a task for a little bit before continuing with the flow. Meaning, some users of `ThreadPool`, after calling `AddTask`, may want to wait for a while (say 1 second) for the task to end, before continuing with the flow. If the task is not done yet, they will continue with the flow anyways.

#### Problem

`ThreadPool` class cannot provide `Wait` interface. Not its responsibility.

#### Solution

1. `ThreadPool` will [SetEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686211(v=vs.85).aspx) when task is done.
2. Users of `ThreadPool` will wait (or not. depend on their need) for the event to be signaled.

So, I've changed the return value of `ThreadPool::AddTask` from `void` to `int` where `int` is a unique task ID which is essentially the name of the event to be singled when a task is done.

#### Question

I don't expect more than ~500 tasks but I'm afraid that creating hundreds of events is not possible or even a bad practice.

So is there a limit? or a better approach?

Comment: If you do go with the event approach, wouldn't it make more sense to return a `HANDLE` (or some RAII wrapped object) from `AddTask` instead of returning an ambiguous `int` that doesn't say much? this way,  you can wait on the task right away instead of looking for the event in some `int` map..

Comment: @David is right, that makes more sense.  That way, you can use unnamed events, which will be more efficient.

Comment: I've actually changed the function to return the event name to be signaled. The handle (worker) that (will) process the task is not determine in `AddTask` scope so I can't return it. I could return the Event itself instead of the event name.

Comment: @idanshmu so you can or can't return a handle? It's not clear.

Comment: I **cannot** return the **thread** `HANDLE`. However, I can pre-allocate an `Event` and **can** return its `HANDLE`. But will required the `ThreadPool` to maintain a map of task to event `HANDLE`

Comment: @idanshmu again, who talked about the thread handle? create an event when `AddTask` starts, return it, and let the threadpool signal it when the task is over. why do you need a map?

Comment: Huh.  I don't see any possible solution that doesn't involve either (a) pre-allocating the event; (b) leaking the event; or (c) a race condition.  How are you doing this at the moment?  (And why can't you store the handle the same way, whatever that is, that you're currently storing the event name?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're asking the wrong question. Fortunately you gave enough background to answer your real question. But before we get to that:

First, **if you're asking what's the maximum number of events a process can open or a system can hold, you're probably doing something very very wrong**. Same goes for asking what's the maximum number of files a process can open or what's the maximum number of threads a process can create.

You can create 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000... but where does it stop? If you're even *considering* creating that many of them that you have to ask about a limit, you're on the wrong track.

Second, **the answer depends on too many implementation details**: OS version, amount of RAM installed, registry settings, and maybe more. Other programs running also affect that "limit".

Third, **even if you knew the limit** - even if you could somehow calculate it at runtime based on all the relevant factors - **it wouldn't allow you to do anything that you can't already do now**.

Lets say you find out the limit is *L* and you have created exactly *L* events by now. Another task come in. What do you do? Throw away the task? Execute the task without signaling an event? Wait until there are fewer than *L* events and only then create an event and start executing the task? Crash the process?

*Whatever* you decide you can do it just the same when `CreateEvent` fails. All of this is completely pointless. And this is yet another indication that you're asking the wrong question.

---

But maybe the most wrong thing you're doing is saying "the thread pool class can't provide `wait` because it's not its responsibility, so lets have the thread pool class provide an event for each task that the thread pool will signal when the task ends" (in paraphrase).

It looks like by the end of the sentence you forgot the premise from the beginning: ***It's not the thread pool's responsibility!***

If you want to wait for the task to finish have the task itself signal when it's done. There's no reason to complicate the thread pool because someone, sometimes want to wait on tasks. Signaling that the task is done is the task's job:

```
event evt;                    ///// this
thread_pool.queue([evt] {
    // whatever
    evt.signal();             ///// and this
});
auto reason = wait(evt, 1s);
if (reason == timeout) {
    log("bummer");
}
```

The `event` class could be anything you want - a Windows event, and `std::promise` and `std::future` pair, or anything else.

This is so simple and obvious.

Complicating the thread pool infrastructure, taking up valuable system resources for nothing, and signaling synchronization primitives even when no one's listening just to save the two marked code lines above in the few cases where you actually want to wait for the task is unjustifiable.

Comment: Excellent point!  I'm not sure I agree with the premise; I think it makes sense for a thread pool to provide a wait service to its clients, depending on context I suppose.  But if it is going to do so, it may as well do so properly, by returning some sort of task object with a .Wait() and other functions as appropriate.  Either way there's no need to generate unnecessary event objects.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Whether or not it makes sense for the thread pool to provide a wait service is out of scope. If it does, there's no question at all. The question assumes it doesn't make sense, and given that it doesn't make sense, the solution is for the task to notify when it's done. I actually think that indeed it doesn't make sense, but that's something that we can discuss in chat if you want.

Comment: No need.  Your answer is right either way, so it's a moot point.

Answer (score 3):

Of course there is *a* limit (if nothing else; at some point the system runs out of memory).

In reality, the limit is around 16 million per process.

You can read more details here: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/markrussinovich/2009/09/29/pushing-the-limits-of-windows-handles/

Comment: The part of the series you linked to deals with *handles* to objects, not the *objects themselves*. The example `DuplicateHandle`s the same event over and over again. But the event itself is stored in the nonpaged pool too. If you were to create new events each and every time, you'd hit the limit earlier, wouldn't you?

Comment: @conio good observation - I didn't think of that. You are probably right - should be easy to test with a small example program though..

Comment: I tried it on a VM with 512MB RAM running 32-bit Windows 10. Sysinternals' `testlimit.exe -h` gave me 16,744,331 (more or less what the link says), while my utility (which simply calls `CreateEvent(nullptr, TRUE, FALSE, nullptr);` in a loop until the call fails) get only to 5,410,357. With 768MB testlimit still gets to 16,744,362 while my utility can create only 9,618,776 events. With 1024MB testlimit again gets the same amount of handles (16,744,362) while my code gets to 13,758,022 events.